# Nested describe and behaviour of dynamically created "it"s

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have nested `describe`s in my tests and as usual I am using some `beforeEach` and before in describes. And one of my `describe` function calls  helper function which creates dynamic tests (DRY). And mocha runs description of nested describe before `beforeEach` method. And my dynamically created `it` has comp as `undefined`.

```
const checkProps = (comp, propName, expectedvalue) => {
   it(`${comp} should have ${propName} equal to ${expectedvalue}`, () => {
       expect(comp.prop(propName)).to.equal(expectedvalue);
   });
};

describe('Component', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  });

   describe('prop checking', () => {
     checkProps(wrapper, 'title', 'SomeTitle');
   });
});
```

What is the best way todo it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**What happens**

The [`Mocha` Run Cycle](https://mochajs.org/#run-cycle-overview) runs all `describe` callback functions first (...which is also true for other testing frameworks such as `Jest` and `Jasmine`).

Then it runs the `before` hooks, then `beforeEach` hooks, and finally the `it` callbacks.

So `checkProps` runs as part of running the initial `describe` callbacks, and at that point `wrapper` is `undefined`, so as you have noticed the test description says `undefined should have...`.

The `beforeEach` hook runs before the `it` callback function runs...but it **redefines** `wrapper` so when the `it` callback runs `comp` is still `undefined` and the test fails:

```
  1) Component
       prop checking
         undefined should have title equal to SomeTitle:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined
      at Context.prop (test/code.test.js:15:19)
```

---

**Solution**

A couple of things need to be changed:

- The component name needs to be available when `it` runs and at that point `wrapper` doesn't exist yet so you'll have to pass the name yourself.
- If you pass an object to `checkProps` then you can set a `wrapper` property on the object during `beforeEach` and access that `wrapper` property within your test since the object is never redefined.

Here is a working test that should get you closer to what you are trying to do:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const MyComponent = () => (<div title="SomeTitle">some text</div>);

const checkProps = (name, obj, propName, expectedvalue) => {
  it(`${name} should have ${propName} equal to ${expectedvalue}`, () => {
    expect(obj.wrapper.prop(propName)).to.equal(expectedvalue);  // Success!
  });
};

describe('Component', () => {
  const obj = {};
  beforeEach(() => {
    obj.wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  });

  describe('prop checking', () => {
    checkProps('MyComponent', obj, 'title', 'SomeTitle');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some basic cases it would work. The reason why I created checkProps to create "it" on fly. like: 
wrapper.find('.subComponents').forEach(subComponent => {
   checkProps(subComponent, 'disabled', false);
});

Comment: You could extend the logic above into the `forEach` call, but at some point it probably makes sense to loop over subcomponents within an `it` instead of looping over the subcomponents to make an `it`  @NurlanMirzayev

Comment: You are right. Just wanted to see which subcomponent has wrong value with help of test title. Thank you ver much, will do that.